# Passport authentication error

Tags: node.js, express, passport-facebook

When I executed the main app along with passport-facebook module I get the following error. I tried `npm install passport-facebook` again but there was no change. I need help to solve this issue. Is `authenticate()` a pre-defined method of passport module?

```
C:\codebag\app\routes.js:53
app.get('/api/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\codebag\app\routes.js:53:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\codebag\server.js:49:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express')
//var router = express.Router();
module.exports = function(app,passport) {
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });

    // route for facebook authentication and login
    app.get('/api/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    app.get('/api/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));

    // route for logging out
    app.get('/api/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

server.js

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var db = require('./config/db');
var passport = require('passport');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
mongoose.connect(db.url); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

Answer (score 2):

In the server.js file I have passed 'app' alone to routes.js using "require('./app/routes')(app)".So I edited this statement to "require('./app/routes')(app,passport)".
Now it works.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not required passport in your router.js, without it, the variable is `undefined`.

Add this to the beginning of the routes.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
```

Comment: Actually I tried it but I get the same error also I reinstalled passport and passport-facebook but no change.